# Troubleshooting: which file contains the error?

Tags: troubleshooting, conky

I currently try to get `gcalcli` working with `conky`. Everything looking good so far, I am just stuck on 1 error:

```
error: argument command: invalid choice: 'calw2'
```

Which makes sense. It should be `calw 2` instead of `calw2`.

Apparently, terminal doesn't tell me which file it tried to run that contains the error. Is there a way to get a log which exactly shows which files are used and in which file the error appears running an application (like here: `conky`) in terminal?

Comment: Does the man page for `conky` offer you a "verbose" or "debug" option?

Comment: `strace` or `sysdig` to figure out what files the application(s) are using, then `grep` those files for `calw2`.

Comment: Why couldn't you just `grep -l 'calw2' *`?

Comment: The `terminal` program isn't intended to tell you anything about these errors - it simply provides a user interface to the shell. It would be your command-line application that should tell you where it encountered a problem.